# How would you access a widget from a function in another file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwidget

I'm developing a project, and I first began making it without GUI, but now I'm porting it to Qt, but I have a problem.

I have my "old" implementation in a separate file, and I try to access the MainWindow widget from it, in order to output to a QTextBrowser, but I'm not able to do so.

In mainwindow.cpp I have this:

```
void MainWindow::addString(char* text)  
     {  
     std::string input = text;  
     ui->textBrowser->append(QString::fromStdString(input));  
     return;  
     }
```

In mainwindow.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow  
     {
     Q_OBJECT
     public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    private slots:
    void on_showWelcome_triggered();
    void on_showArithmetic_triggered();
    private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    public slots:
    void btnResolveClicked();
    void btnClearClicked();
    void hideAll();
    void addString(char* output);
    };
    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And in simple_mode.cpp:

```
void test()  
     {
     MainWindow *gui = new MainWindow;
     gui->addString("WORKS");
     MainWindow:: = gui;  
     }
```

However this doesnt append "WORKS" to the textbrowser, which is what I need, I think it adds it to another instance of text browser which isnt the same as the mainwindow.

EDIT:
What I wanted to do was appending a line of text directly from simple_mode.cpp to the textbrowser. 
By the way, simple_mode was written without any Qt aid, that's why I used std strings, and currently the textbrowser widget acts as a virtual terminal output screen, and instead of using printf like I did before, I wanted to append lines to the textbrowser. However I already found my way through, I don't need this now.

I needed help

Comment: I'm always willing to learn: what does `MainWindow:: = gui;` mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell what do you want to achieve and pieces of code do not cover all possible erroneous areas (i.e. where's the `MainWindow` constructor's definition?). Also, the formatting is terrible - please use idents and consistent bracing style.

My advice is simply call `show` on `MainWindow` instance. Unless you don't mess up `ui` initialization in `MainWindow` constructor, this snippet should be enough. If it is not - supply us with missing pieces of code.

```
void test()  
{
    MainWindow *gui = new MainWindow;
    gui->addString("WORKS");
    gui->show();
}
```

As a side note, your `addString` method should look like this:

```
void MainWindow::addString(char* text)
{
    ui->textBrowser->append(QString::fromAscii(text));
}
```

Return statement is completely unnecessary, and assigning `text` to `std::string` is likely to cause unnecessary memory allocation. It's not like it is the end of the world, but it's really, really bad practice for a C++ programmer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry about my formatting, its my first question and I didnt0 quite understand the editor.

Comment: We all have to learn. Could you please relate to questions and suggestions from my post?

Comment: @JGDames, could you please take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901888/qt-read-access-error-when-attempting-to-use-any-function-from-another-widget-c) to point out my mistake? I believe my problem is relevant to your solution here. Thanks!